# maintain prompt despite ouput flow

Tags: scripting, terminal, input

#### Short version

Can I maintain an input symbol (`>` for instance) at the bottom of the terminal so that the user can input despite text flowing above?

#### Long version

I am making a multi-process application that basically deal with text flow (with telnet input and output in the near future). I put a prompt symbol `>` with printf to tell the user that he can write. But if some children answer a bit late to the previous input, the output is written after that prompt, and even if it technically still works, it is not very practical.

Is there a way to maintain a empty line with a prompt to type even if text is 'scrolling' above?

Comment: Sounds like a problem that ncurses could help with -- maintaining two separate logical windows, one small one for input and another for output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a wrapper object that serialize all the output streams. It is likely that you are going to need mutexes to syncronize this.

You can then print a '>' after each children process output, this way the last line will always be the '>'.

Comment: I didn't thought about that, I'll try, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the dead-simple version that's just "always maintain the prompt line after the most recent output line", you can do something like always outputting `"\routput here\n> "` (to overwrite the most recent prompt line, write output, then write a new prompt line). If you want the user to be able to keep their input across new output lines, you'd need to do something fancy a bit like `readline`/`libedit` does. (There may actually be an option to those to do this; I'm not sure.) The general process would be to go into cbreak/raw mode, maintain an in-memory buffer of just what the user has typed, then output it again after the prompt whenever you write a new output line.